# Ethminer Ubuntu 16 not using NVIDIA GPU

Tags: ethereum

I have followed instructions [here](https://forum.ethereum.org/discussion/comment/8889/#Comment_8889) and successfully build and setup geth. 
Ethminer seems to work except it doesn't use the Titan X GPU and the mining rate is only 341022 H/s.

Also when I try to use the -G option ethminer says it is an invalid argument; the -G flag also doesn't appear in the ethminer help command.

Answer (score 0):

Your GPU must have a minimum memory to perform mining. Upgrade to GPU you with higher memories (minimum 4GB is preferable)
The current DAG size is above (2GB). That means you cant mine with GPU with memory less than 2GB.

Comment: the Nvidia Titan X has 12 GB of GPU memory. I found out that ethminer no longer supports GPU mining on NVIDIA but there is a forked version that does support ubuntu but I'm having trouble building it.